# to see list of user with disk consumed what in my disk

Tags: disk-usage

How can I see list of  user occupying a disk in my assigned folder in unix

and what amount of disk they are  occupying  currently

If there is any command available which I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Changed `uniq | sort | uniq` to `sort -u`.

You could obtain a list of users by find:

```
find -printf "%u" | sort -u
```

(In my experience first `uniq` often makes a list much shorter to sort).

If I had to sum bytes I would use find and awk:

```
find -type f -printf "%u %s\n" | awk '{usage[$1]+=$2} END {for(user in usage){print "User: " user " occupies: " usage[user] " bytes"}}'
```

Finds prints username and file size in bytes. See `man find`.

Awk sums bytes for every user in table. At the end summary is printed.

Comment: I think `sort -u` would be simpler and faster than `uniq | sort | uniq`.

Comment: @Fiximan, Than you. I should have thought of that!